# Creating buckets on percentage column using SQL (Bigquery)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to create buckets using SQL (BigQuery) on a conversion column [data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1puAo7NiE52wZRbBAQA8DOd81PJTzf068uWDszP2eQVA/edit#gid=831713531). Please refer Dataset_2.

I wrote the below query, but i'm only getting one row.

Result:

Row buckets
1     >50

```
SELECT
  buckets
FROM (
  SELECT
    Conversion__,
    CASE
      WHEN Conversion__ > 30 AND Conversion__ <=40 THEN '31-40'
      WHEN Conversion__ > 40 AND Conversion__ <=50 THEN '41-50'
    ELSE '>50'
  END
    AS buckets
  FROM
    data_2) t2
GROUP BY
  buckets
```

Comment: Edit your question and show sample data and desired results *in the question*.  It is unclear what you are trying to generate.

Comment: What is the data type of the column Conversion__?

Comment: The data type is float and I've added the link to data set as well. What i need is a table with two columns one showing count and other showing bucket. I think it will only have 3 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN Conversion__ > 30 AND Conversion__ <=40 THEN '31-40'
    WHEN Conversion__ > 40 AND Conversion__ <=50 THEN '41-50'
    ELSE '>50'
  END AS buckets, 
COUNT(*) AS cnt  
FROM data_2
GROUP BY buckets
```

If applied to provided sample data - output is

[image]

Comment: glad it works for you. please consider also voting up the answer :o)